# Split a data-frame based in ordered multi factorial column

Tags: r, split, subsequence

I would like to split a data-frame in a list of data-frames. The reasoning to split it is that we will have always `father` followed by `mother` which in turn is followed by `offspring`. However, these family members might have more than one row (which are always subsequent. e.g `father` number 1 is in the row 1 and row 2). In my below example I have two families, then I am trying to get a list with two data-frames.

My input:

```
df <- 'Chr  Start   End Family
1   187546286   187552094   father
3   108028534   108032021   father
1   4864403 4878685 mother
1   18898657    18904908    mother
2   460238  461771  offspring
3   108028534   108032021   offspring
1   71481449    71532983    father
2   74507242    74511395    father
2   181864092   181864690   mother
1   71481449    71532983    offspring
2   181864092   181864690   offspring
3   160057791   160113642   offspring'

df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

Thus, my expected output `dfout[[1]]` would look like:

```
dfout <- 'Chr   Start   End Family
1   187546286   187552094   father
3   108028534   108032021   father
1   4864403 4878685 mother
1   18898657    18904908    mother
2   460238  461771  offspring
3   108028534   108032021   offspring'

dfout - read.table(text=dfout, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what logic you have that dictates when you go from one family to the next down the rows of your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split each family into a separate data frame, you will need an index indicating where one family ends and another begins. For the index, I used "father" as the change-point. But we cannot simply use `indx <- df$Family == "father"` since there can be multiple 'father' entries in a row. Instead we test where the switch from 'offspring' to 'father' by searching for where it equals 1.

```
indx <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(df$Family == "father")) == 1L)
split(df, indx)
# $`1`
#   Chr     Start       End    Family
# 1   1 187546286 187552094    father
# 2   3 108028534 108032021    father
# 3   1   4864403   4878685    mother
# 4   1  18898657  18904908    mother
# 5   2    460238    461771 offspring
# 6   3 108028534 108032021 offspring
# 
# $`2`
#    Chr     Start       End    Family
# 7    1  71481449  71532983    father
# 8    2  74507242  74511395    father
# 9    2 181864092 181864690    mother
# 10   1  71481449  71532983 offspring
# 11   2 181864092 181864690 offspring
# 12   3 160057791 160113642 offspring
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you posted the code you use to produce your actual data frame.  I don't have time to redo everything, but I'll show you how it works, in a generic sense.

```
gender <- c("M","M","F","F","F","F","M","M","M","M","F","F")
values <- c(20,22,24,19,9,17,18,22,12,14,7,8)
fruit <- c("apple","pear","mango","mango","mango","apple","banana","banana","banana","mango","apple","apple")
df <- data.frame(gender, values, fruit)


> df
   gender values  fruit
1       M     20  apple
2       M     22   pear
3       F     24  mango
4       F     19  mango
5       F      9  mango
6       F     17  apple
7       M     18 banana
8       M     22 banana
9       M     12 banana
10      M     14  mango
11      F      7  apple
12      F      8  apple

split(df, df$gender)

$F
   gender values fruit
3       F     24 mango
4       F     19 mango
5       F      9 mango
6       F     17 apple
11      F      7 apple
12      F      8 apple

$M
   gender values  fruit
1       M     20  apple
2       M     22   pear
7       M     18 banana
8       M     22 banana
9       M     12 banana
10      M     14  mango
```